# How to write the query to get week wise datas in xml page.as my codes as follows

Tags: mysql, xml

can you help me to find the mistake in my code

```
    Select DATE_FORMAT(createddate, '%Y-%m-%d') AS DAY,
     DATE_FORMAT(createddate, '%Y-%m') AS MONTH,
     DATE_FORMAT(createddate, '%Y') AS YEAR  
    createddate between CAST(#{fromdate} AS DATE) and DATE_ADD(CAST(#{todate}  AS DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
         <if test="filtertype =='day' ">
        group by DATE(createddate) order by createddate ASC;
        </if>
         <if test="filtertype =='week' ">
        group by WEEK(createddate) order by createddate ASC;
        </if>
          <if test="filtertype =='month' ">
        group by MONTH(createddate) order by createddate ASC;
        </if>
         <if test="filtertype =='year' ">
        group by YEAR(createddate) order by createddate ASC;
        </if>
```

this is my code to fetch datas by filtering

Comment: This is non valid MySQL code ...

Comment: can you please tell me the reason,?

Comment: Well XML syntax is nested inbetween SQL syntax ...

Comment: please help me to find the correct query for week wise data selection?

Comment: *"please help me to find the correct query for week wise data selection?"* i advice you to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) especially the **"Help others reproduce the problem/Proof-read before posting!"** part  as the question is missing basic information which we need to answer/help ...

Comment: then see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) on help how to provide example data and expected results without we  can't really help..

Comment: Sir i really need is, wants to display datas on the table group wise(week,month,year).

Comment: for that ..iam putting a if condition inside the ''group by ''syntax that i shown above.